# Find the length/size of an integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an integer array `int[] a = new int [5]`.

In my code I am storing only 2 values at indices 0 and 1.

`a[0]=100` and `a[1]=101`

Now I need to get the array size/length as 2.

What I should do?

Comment: What's the wider context? Chances are there's a much better way of doing things than you've said here.

Comment: i dont know the size of the array initially. but after i store elemnts in my array i need to trim the array by removing unset indices

Answer (score 9):

You array length is 5, not 2. You've defined your array to be 5 elements long, how many you ended up using is irrelevant.

What can you do instead is this:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(100);
a.add(101);
System.out.println(a.size());
```

will give you 2

Answer (score 6):

You can't - there's no difference between an element which hasn't been set and an element which has been set to 0. The actual length of the array is 5, and will always be 5. (Arrays can't change in length after creation.)

Of course, if you know that you'll never use 0, you could write:

```
int size = 0;
for (int value : a)
{
    if (value != 0)
    {
        size++;
    }
}
```

... but if you're trying to use the array as a buffer with a "live" segment at the start (like `ArrayList` does) then you'll have to maintain that size yourself.

Comment: +1 Personally I would have told exact same, but distinguishing primitive int from boxed type Integer, with what this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the size of the array. However, you can make a new array with the correct size and copy the data you are interested in into the new array.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the array and check the last index that isn't 0 - or if you use the `Integer` type you could do the same check but check for null instead of 0. But this won't give you the length, it's merely a poor estimate for how many values you've used.

A far better way would be to use an arraylist and then get the size of that. You're most likely using arrays for the wrong purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList` or `Vector` .

```
Vector intvec = new Vector();
intvec.add(100);
intvec.add(101);
System.out.println(intvec.size());
```

Comment: Please don't mention Vector as it's pretty much not used anymore.

Comment: @Steve  may be it is not, but still my favorite data structure.